# Debian 8 Jessie UEFI Install

Tags: debian, uefi

I am installing Debian 8 Jessie on a UEFI system. I have to set up RAID so I am using manual partitioning. The system installs fine in BIOS compatibility mode but there doesnt seem to be a UEFI installation option in there. Is there a non-obvious way to do that or is it not possible to do a UEFI install through the installer?

Comment: This is not a programming question - it belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot your PC in UEFI mode, not BIOS compatibility. You will see a different installer that says "UEFI Installer".

[image]

To compare with a regular installer:

[image]

Comment: I did but nothing shows up in boot menu. Which install image is this?

Comment: This is `debian-8.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso`.

Comment: Tried. Still not working. Says "Selected boot image did not Authenticate. Press <Enter> to Continue."

Comment: You need to disable the Secure Boot, and possible delete/reset the authentication keys.

Comment: The answer is fine, but it does not belong on this site. Can it be migrated with question?

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. So now the system will boot in UEFI but Secure Boot will remain disabled?

Comment: To get Debian working with Secure Boot you need some extra work. Google "linux shim uefi".

Comment: I searched but its very unclear what to do really. This will need some work.